# Problems with AutoCompleteTextView on Actionbar/Toolbar

Tags: android, material-design

I've some issues with width of this element when I put it on a toolbar or actionbar. Look like this:

[image: Toolbar problem]

No problems with SearchView:

[image: SearchView is ok]

With SearchView it will be ok, but don't wanna be putting workaround in my code.
What can I do? I'm using the last version of appcompat library.

search_custom:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView_searchWidget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="text">
    <requestFocus/>
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

Menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:name="search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/search_custom"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>

</menu>
```

Gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
```

**SOLVED! BEAUTIFUL WORKAROUND:**

```
int screenWidth = new ViewUtil(this).getScreenWidth(); // This guy return the width of the device
if(screenWidth <= 10) {
    creenWidth = 150;
}
mAutoCompleteTextView.setMinWidth(screenWidth);
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem.

Comment: And now? I've changed the infos of the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the minWidth on your AutoCompleteTextView

Answer (score 0):

In my case work this code:

`textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`